# Binding selected ListBox Image somewhere else in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have seen few answers here to similar questions, but none of them were helpful in my case.
I have ListBox with images, binded to ObservableCollection as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="gallery" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Gallery}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="ImageSelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ImageData}">
            <Label Padding="4" Height="90">
                <Image ToolTip="{Binding ImageGuid}" 
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"  
                                     DecodePixelHeight="90"  
                                     CacheOption="OnLoad" 
                                     CreateOptions="DelayCreation">
                        </BitmapImage>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And I'm trying to bind the selected image to Grid in different part of the Window, but the approach I took isn't working.

SelectionChanged event is trying to pass selected item as ImageData extracted from, well, ListBox selection:

```
    private void ImageSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ImageData;
        bigImage.DataContext = obj;
    }
```

And XAML code responsible for showing the big picture:

```
    <Grid x:Name="bigImage"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label Padding="4" Height="90">
            <Image ToolTip="{Binding ImageGuid}" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}">
                    </BitmapImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
```

It gives me exception about UriSource not being set.

Could somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

**Solution based on Peregrine's and Clemens's answers:**

Source Listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="gallery" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Gallery}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ImageData}">
            <Label Padding="4" Height="90">
                <Image ToolTip="{Binding ImageGuid}" 
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Destination Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="bigImage" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=gallery, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <Label Padding="4" Height="90">
        <Image ToolTip="{Binding ImageGuid}" 
               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `DataType="{x:Type model:ImageData}"` on the ItemTemplate is redundant. However, it indicates that the items are of a different type than what you try to use in `(sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ImageModel`. Please clarify the relation between ImageData and ImageModel. Besides that, the explicit BitmapImage in bigImage also seems redundant. You could as well write `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" ... />`.

Comment: That was an error while copying the code, corrected. Going to try the answer provided by Peregrine

Comment: You get that exception because the SelectedItem may also be null, i.e. also the DataContext can be null and hence the `ImageUrl` Binding produces a null value. BitmapImage won't tolerate that. The exception won't occur with `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" ... />`

Comment: Yours and Peregrine's answer helped me A LOT! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a tool such as [WPF Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) to check that bigImage.DataContext really is being set as expected.

You can also set that grid's DataContext by direct data binding, rather than using events in code behind

```
<Grid x:Name="bigImage" DataContect="{Binding ElementName=gallery, Path=SelectedItem}" ...
```

Since the SelectedItem property may be `null`, you should also directly bind the Image's Source property to avoid any exceptions that BitmapImage may throw for a UriSource Binding that produces a null value:

```
<Image ToolTip="{Binding ImageGuid}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
```